# Using grep to identify a pattern

Tags: linux, grep

I have several documents hosted on a cloud instance. I want to extract all words conforming to a specific pattern into a `.txt` file. This is the pattern:

```
ABC123A
ABC123B
ABC765A
```

and so one. Essentially the words start with a specific character string 'ABC', have a fixed number of numerals, and end with a letter. This is my code:

```
grep -oh ABC[0-9].*[a-zA-Z]$ > /home/user/abcLetterMatches.txt
```

When I execute the query, it runs for several hours without generating any output. I have over 1100 documents. However, when I run this query:

```
grep -r ABC[0-9].*[a-zA-Z]$ > /home/user/abcLetterMatches.txt
```

the list of files with the strings is generated in a matter for seconds.

What do I need to correct in my query? Also, what is causing the delay?

UPDATE 1

Based on the answers, it's evident that the command is missing the file name on which it needs to be executed. I want to run the code on multiple document files (>1000)

The documents I want searched are in multiple sub-directories within a directory. What is a good way to search through them? Doing

```
grep -roh ABC[0-9].*[a-zA-Z]$ > /home/user/abcLetterMatches.txt
```

only returns the file names.

UPDATE 2

If I use the updated code from the answer below:

```
find . -exec grep -oh "ABC[0-9].*[a-zA-Z]$" >> ~/abcLetterMatches.txt {} \;
```

I get a `no file or directory` error

UPDATE 3

The pattern can be anywhere in the line.

Comment: ‘*runs for several hours without generating any output*’ That's because it's waiting for input. You didn't tell `grep` *where* to look, so it's reading STDIN. You'll want to do `grep <pattern> <file>`.

Comment: Your pattern will match things that aren't like your examples, e.g. `ABC1fooA`. Your pattern just requires a single digit after `ABC`, then anything`.

Comment: Your pattern will extract `ABC123A` from patterns like `356XYZABC123A`. Is this intended?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regexp :

```
~/  grep -E "^ABC[0-9]{3}[A-Z]$" docs > filename
ABC123A
ABC123B
ABC765A
```

Comment: Will match everything that contains your pattern such as `XYZABC123A2356fghf65`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no delay, `grep` is just waiting for the input you didn't give it (and therefore it waits on standard input, by default). You can correct your command by supplying argument with filename:

```
grep -oh "ABC[0-9].*[a-zA-Z]$" file.txt > /home/user/abcLetterMatches.txt
```

Source (`man grep`):

```
SYNOPSIS
       grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
```

To perform the same grepping on several files recursively, combine it with `find` command:

```
find . -exec grep -oh "ABC[0-9].*[a-zA-Z]$" >> ~/abcLetterMatches.txt {} \;
```

Comment: Put the pattern in quotes.

Comment: @Barmar, just did it.

Comment: I see. I want to run the command on a bunch of directories that have the documents. Checking by individual file is not a feasible option given that there are so many of them. I'm editing the question to include this information.

Comment: @kurious I have added it to my answer.

Comment: I tried -roh. it writes the file name, not the exact matches

Comment: @kurious try it one more time, I've edited my answer quickly but you may have checked the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you ask for:

```
grep -hr '^ABC[0-9]\{3\}[A-Za-z]$'
```

- `-h` to not get the filenames.
- `-r` to search **r**ecursively. If no directory is given (as above) the current one is used. Otherwise just specify one as the last argument.
- Quotes around the pattern to avoid accidental globbing, etc.
- `^` at the beginning of the pattern to — together with `$` at the end — only match whole lines. (Not sure if this was a requirement, but the sample data suggests it.)
- `\{3\}` to specify that there should be three digits.
- No `.*` as that would match a whole lot of other things.

Comment: the pattern can be anywhere in the line. updated the question accordingly. it will be great if you can edit your answer accordingly.